# Is there even a slight possibility to process two lists in one single list comprehension line?

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I would like to ask if there's a possibility to process more than one list in just a single line with list comprehension? I'm using Python 2.7 .

Here is what the code looks like:

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
m=[1,7]
c=[]

for x in m:
    if x in n:
        c.append(x)
        n.pop(n.index(x))

print n
print c
```

The output is:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
[1,7]
```

Now I'm wondering if I could turn the code (line 5 to line 8) into a single line using a list comprehension?

I would appreciate your advice. Let me know if my question has a duplicate. Thank you very much.

Comment: probably not (because of that pop) but what is exactly you want to do?

Comment: if you only need to remove items from n that are present in m, then, no problem

Comment: Oh. I'm trying to (if possible) make my code run faster because I've noticed that my program runs slow in dealing large numbers and I was hoping that doing list comprehension can make it run faster?

Comment: what is `index(x)` ??

Comment: what is your code doing? looks like you could use `sets` to speed up this operation but your question doesn't make much sense if you don't give us some context.

Comment: I've edited the index(x). Sorry.

Comment: Yea that makes more sense

Comment: if your goal is to speed up your code and you are dealing with relatively large lists, list comprehensions may not be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way since popping a value from the list returns the value

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
m=[1,7]
c=[n.pop(n.index(x)) for x in m if x in n]
print n
print c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
m=[1,7]
print set(n)-set(m)
> [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Assign the sets to their own variables if you need to perform additional operations. Converting to a set will take some time on a big list but then membership, subtraction, union or intersection operations should be very fast.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should learn set() first. But why is that I can only check (green) one answer?